# vim - Change Line number Highlight upon inserts/normal

Tags: vim

I want to be able to highlight the active line one color for NORMAL mode and another for INSERT. I have the conoline but it doesn’t work for nvim, which i occasionally like to use and i’m sure there’s a more compact way to do this anyway

I tried this but it throws an error:

```
autocmd InsertEnter * :set highlight LineNr ctermfg=blue ctermbg=red
autocmd InsertLeave * :set highlight LineNr ctermfg=blue ctermbg=red
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

`highlight` is a command, not an option for `set`. See `:help highlight`.

```
autocmd InsertEnter * :highlight LineNr ctermfg=blue ctermbg=red
autocmd InsertLeave * :highlight LineNr ctermfg=blue ctermbg=red
```